# Can it be that the formula for calc vlsr for sun have a part beginning with cos270 for Calculate sun/VLSR.cos 270=0?

Tags: radio-astronomy, radio

I am working radioastronomy and have a formula for sun/earth calculation.

The formula for sun begin with $20(\cos270 \cos 30 \ldots\ldots+$

Question:

The first part is $\cos270=0$ and is that correct in the formulas attached.

https://advlabwiki.johnshopkins.edu/images/Vlsr.pdf

Vr(sun) = 20.0 [cos 270° cos 30° cos α cos δ + sin 270° cos 30° sin α cos δ + sin 30° sin δ] (km/s)

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome it looks like JamesK has understood what the actual question is sufficiently to answer it, and I've added the expression in question back into the question itself.

Comment: [This question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/41196/looking-for-a-routine-to-correct-for-local-standard-of-rest-lsr) might be related or useful :-)

Comment: I know the formula and james have the answer  - thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for a direction with $α = 18 \mathrm{hr}$, or $270^◦$ and $δ = 30^◦$ it is correct to have a term in the dot product with $\cos 270$.  It is merely a coincidence that that is zero.

The true value of the direction isn't exactly 270<sup>◦</sup>, so you can easily adjust the formula to a more accurate value later. A more precise value is 277<sup>◦</sup> or 18hr 28min.

Comment: Hi james me again - yes from Denmark. 
I already have been trying to put in 271 and so on - but I felt it was not the right thing to do. And it dident make mutch chance in result. Sorry for my typing error. again thank you james

Comment: If this solves your problem, you may mark it as accepted by clicking on the green "tick".

Comment: Where do I find the green tick?